# Design view of Form class that inherits from BaseForm<T>

Tags: c#, forms

I'm having a problema displaying a form in Visual Studio design view, because this form inherits from another base form class that in turns takes a generic type parameter.

Example:

```
class BaseForm<T> : Form where T : class, new()
{
..... code
}
```

Then we have another form that uses this BaseForm.

```
class RecordForm : BaseForm<DBUserEntry>
{
..... code
}
```

The form code compiles and I can show a RecordForm on demand. However in the design view its another story, I can see BaseForm in design view, but I cannot view RecordForm in design view and Visual Studio reports the following when I try.

> Warning   1   The designer could not be shown for this file because none
>   of the classes within it can be designed.  The designer inspected the
>   following classes in the file:
>
> RecordForm --- The base class
>   'SampleApp.Forms.Base.BaseForm' could not
>   be loaded.  Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all
>   projects have been built.

Makes little sense since it compiles without errors and the sample application shows the RecordForm.

Its caused by the generic type parameter in BaseForm, its the only "out of norm" thing in the code. Does anyone knows how to get design view working in forms that inherit another class with generic type parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877217/can-visual-studio-designer-show-classes-inheriting-generic-types

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797279/win-forms-designer-error-when-inheriting-from-a-generic-form

Comment: @Fabio: The wrapper worked. Good thinking. Thanks.